# How to block IP address or IP classes in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, security

I need to block one IP address or class in asp.net

Can anyone help me with the code? And how to implement?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the IP address of the client using the [`HttpRequest.UserHostAddress` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress(v=VS.100).aspx) (an instance can be accessed using `this.Request` from any page or using static property `HttpContext.Current`).

As far as I know, there is no standard method that would compare the IP address with a specified range, so you'll need to implement this bit yourself.

You'll probably want to check this for every request, which can be done either in the `OnInit` method of every page (that you want to block) or in the [`BeginRequest` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest.aspx) of the application (typically in `Global.asax`).

If you detect a blocked address, you can output an empty (placeholder) page using [`Server.Transfer` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.transfer.aspx) (`Response.End` would be another alternative, but that simply cuts the page - returning an empty page, while `Server.Transfer` allows you to output some message to the client).

Comment: I know how to get it, but I don't know how to block it. I'm not very familiar with asp.net

Comment: Also, this should be done on a HttpModule since you don't want to consume resources of your web server by processing innecesarily the request if the IP is blocked.

Comment: @FinalDestiny: Added the rest of the answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

If what you mean by "block" is "don't let them harass my server", this is not an asp.net issue, you need a firewall (software or hardware).

If what you mean by "block" is "don't show my pages":

```
' pseudocode, I haven't checked the exact syntax

Sub Page_Load()
    If HttpRequest.UserHostAddress = "123.123.123.1" then
        Response.Redirect "404.htm" ' send them elsewhere
    end if
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for the suggestion of handling this kind of thing at the firewall level instead of at the software level, when possible.

Answer (score 0):

you mention you are not familiarized with the ASP.NET, so, maybe this excelent article from [Rick](http://www.west-wind.com) can help you as it as a full article on how to block IP's and even have an admin area to manage them...

> http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/59731.aspx