# .net core CORS setup is not blocking calls from Postman

Tags: .net, cors

I have .net core api application where I have implemented cors with restricted origins. This is working fine, if I call api from browser and origin is not matched call get blocked but if I call the same api from postman I get the result even if origin header is missing or I add origin header manually.

I need to block any call which is not initiated from my front-end app

Comment: please provide your code with CORS configuration

Comment: CORS configuration isn’t a means to cause servers to block requests. Instead it’s just a way for servers to tell browsers whether they want browsers to allow frontend JavaScript code to access responses from cross-origin requests. See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43432743/will-asp-net-core-cors-policy-prevent-resource-access-from-non-browser-requests/43432787#43432787 etc. If you want your server to reject any request not initiated by your front-end app, CORS configuration isn’t the way; you’d need some other mechanism.

Comment: So can this be achieved by some middle layer. Do you have any example?

Comment: @sideshowbarker would you mind giving an example?

Comment: @Amthieu Search for “asp net ip-based blocking” or such. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2893252/441757, https://stackoverflow.com/q/16080487/441757, https://stackoverflow.com/a/4605086/441757, etc., and https://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnIPAddressBlockingHttpModuleForASPNETIn9Minutes.aspx,